# How to dry run the program code ' binary to decimal '

Tags: java, binary, decimal

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package binary_to_decaimal;


import java.util.*;
public class Binary_to_Decaimal {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int n,dec=0,i=0,N=0;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number in binary form like 0 1 or 1 0");
        n=in.nextInt();
        while(n > 0)

        {
            dec = n % 10;
             N =N+ dec *( int)Math.pow(2,i);
            i++;
            n=n/10;
        }
        System.out.println("Decimal \t"+N);
    }
}
```

How to dry run above program when binary is 11(3) and get the desired decimal number?

Comment: What do you mean by "dry run" here?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Please try to explain again what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Make the conversion a method and write a test?

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you:

```
public int getDecimalFromBinary(int binary){

    int decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;
    while(true){
        if(binary == 0){
            break;
        } else {
            int tmp = binary%10;
            decimal += tmp*Math.pow(2, power);
            binary = binary/10;
            power++;
        }
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: Explain me the concept on each iteration what happens to the following line of code.   dec = n % 10;
                 N =N+ dec *( int)Math.pow(2,i);
                i++;
                n=n/10;